# Laptop shuts down during boot sequence

Tags: boot, laptop, battery, reboot

I managed to destroy the hard drive of my laptop. So I formatted it and suddenly I am not able to boot anymore. If I try to boot with all different sorts of bootable CDs/DVDs immediately after the boot starts (that is, the boot CD/DVD is accessed) the computer shuts down.

The strange thing is that booting from the HD and/or from external media worked fine until yesterday. I don't know why it stopped working

The model is: Lenovo Thinkpad W530

I already tried the following things:

- Remove battery and AC and press power button for a few seconds
- Boot with battery removed and only AC attached
- I did the complete hardware check of the BIOS (CPU, Motherboard, RAM, etc.). It identified no issues
- I tried to boot without the HD

I read in other threads that the reason could be overheating, but I doubt it, because it worked just fine a few hours ago.

My question is: What could be the reason that the computer cannot boot anymore with any kind of (external) media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern UEFI (BIOS) has [Secure Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/116569/htg-explains-how-windows-8s-secure-boot-feature-works-what-it-means-for-linux/), which checks the boot loader before launching it to ensure it’s digitally signed.

There are a few ways around this:

- In UEFI setup, disable Secure Boot (and you may also need to disable Fast Boot. as well).
- An alternative is to [add your boot loader's signature](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html).
- You *might* be able to download a full Windows 10 ISO from MS, but if you've lost the original product key, the installation will not complete.

Comment: The Secure Boot option was already disabled, however, I changed from UEFI boot to Legacy boot. Now it works. Thank you so much!